# What library or pattern reduces boilerplate for this many cb to 1 cb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I find myself writing something like this a lot in my code, and I'm sure there's a standard library out there that makes this a lot simpler - hopefully a one liner.  Essentially I want to write an async handler for an array, that does some async work per item in the array, and calls back regarding all work on the array either: (A) after every single item in the array was async handled successfully, or (B) if there was any error, exiting early if possible - BUT only such that the master callback is called precisely once.

Hoping for an answer that works for both browser and node:

```
// @items - an array
// @cb - callback after all of `items` processed, taking an optional Error first argument
function doForEachAndCb(items, cb) {
  var exitEarly, tasksRemaining;
  if (!items || typeof items !== 'object' || !items.length) {
    cb();
    return;
  }

  tasksRemaining = items.length;
  exitEarly = false;

  function finishOneTask(err) {
    // finishOneTask() is no-op if previously called with an error passed.
    if (exitEarly) {
      return;
    }
    if (!!err) {
      exitEarly = true;
      cb(err);
      return;
    }
    tasksRemaining--;
    if (tasksRemaining === 0) {
      cb();
    }
  }

  items.map( (v) => {
    try {
      handleItemAsync(items[v], finishOneTask);
    } catch (err2) {
      finishOneTask(err2);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The appropriately named library [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)  is good for general callback utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`async#map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map):

```
async.map(items, (item, callback) => {
  // do something async
  ...
  // when async operation has finished, call
  // the callback with the mapped value
  callback(null, value);
}, (err, mappedItems) => {
  ...
});
```

If you have no need to build an array of mapped values, you can use [`async#each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachcoll-iteratee-callback) instead.

Both `async#map()` and `async#each()` also have a sequential version, where each item is processed only after the previous processing step has completed (the "regular" versions process all items in parallel): `async#mapSeries()` and `async#eachSeries()`.